# I got a problem with the mobile media query UI, on the navbar list there are spaces, but I haven't added any padding or margins

Tags: html, css, media-queries, navbar

[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huwRN.png)
[vs Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pgMV.png)

i have remove the padding from media query, but not effect

Comment: Please Add [example]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** That's maybe because you have set margin or padding on element while you was coding for normal screen width, and after that when you're coding media queries for smaller screens sometimes you need to add **!important** after change on css.

**Example:**

```
li{
padding: 0 !important; 
margin: 0 !important;
}
```

**Option 2:** That's maybe bacause you're using display: flex; and justify-content: space-between, space-evenly or space-around (Display flex are adding spaces that cannot be removed with margin or padding 0). Try to use justify-content: center; or justify-content: start; on the ul tag.

**Example:**

```
ul{
justify-content: start !imporant;
}
```

*If this doesn't work try to find another solution...*